# How to filter a query by one more column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

As a data analyst, I'm trying to get a specific string from Google Sheets with a query, so that my table can be more filtered with useful information.

This is my current query which is working, but I would like to add another column as a filter.

Current query (which works):

`=query('Observations Table - Live'!A:H,"select C, sum(B) where B is not null group by C pivot A",1)`

The query I'm trying to use but is not working:

`=query('Observations Table - Live'!A:H,"select C, H sum(B) where B is not null and H = 'STRING' group by C pivot A",1)`

Comment: You forgot a comma : `,` in your query here between `H` and `sum(B)` :  `[..] C, H sum(B) [..]`